# How to update scheduler job credentials in oracle enterprise manager?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, jobs

I have a job scheduled in oracle 11g which runs on daily basis. Job is running with User "user_dba" (unix server user). The job is failing from the day I changed the password for the user "user_dba". I navigated to `scheduler jobs` in OEM and found the credential name "user_dba_credential". The job is failing because this named credential still has old password where as I have changed the password. So can anyone please tell me how to update the password in the "user_dba_credential" to my new password via OEM?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 12c you can edit the named credentials by navigating to **Setup > Security > Named Credentials**

In Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control you should look at **Preferences > Preferred Credentials**, [here is the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11857_01/em.111/e16790/jobs.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but i am using Oracle Enterprise manager 11g. No oprion of security in setup. if you have any info on OEM 11g kindly help me get to that screen.

Comment: @newbie_123: I have expanded my answer

Comment: I guess the credentials in this screen are not the credentials used by the job. Or i have understood wrong.
I need the functionality of `DBMS_CREDENTIAL.UPDATE_CREDENTIAL('cred_name','PASSWORD','new_pswrd')` in OEM. Is this possible in OEM?